# Laravel macOS Unexpected character in input: '

Tags: php, macos, laravel-5, visual-studio-code, vagrant

i installed Vagrant on my macOS with the Parallels provider.
I created a new project with the command `laravel new blog`.

When i opened the site everything works fine. Then i want to add an auth with these commands: `php artisan make:auth` `php artisan migrate`

The first command works fine but the second produces errors:

> PHP Warning:  Unexpected character in input:  ' in /home/vagrant/blog/routes/web.php on line 17

I figured out that the problem is between the vagrant box "homestead" and macOS. Because after i turned off the sync between homestead and macOS and reinstalled the whole project it worked fine. So can you tell me where the problem is? Is it the charset?

This is what my web.php looks like (i made no changes):

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: I would go with Laravel Valet or Valet-Plus instead of a whole virtual machine.
But: What does your routes/web.php looks like?

Comment: Does anyone has a solution. I get this warning on more and more files. It seems to be that the sync between macOS and homestead is broken. But i dont know where the problem is.

Comment: Try to remove `Auth::routes();` since these routes are already there.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me also. Enabling NFS solved my problem. Not sure what is the cause.

Homestead.yaml

```
folders:
- map: ~/code
  to: /home/vagrant/code
  type: "nfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

If somebody still running into this problem,the solution for me was:

Exit from vagrant ,and once out of it, reload the vagrant VM and enter again to your project folder and run:

- `composer dump-autoload`
- `php artisan migrate`

After that ,im not getting the error and the column in my case is being created in the DB table